# How to pass derived object as parent object in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I was working with core OOP model.
Where i am having some issues.

with "this" keyword. here is the sample code of what I am trying to achieve.

```
class equation {
// some properties
};
class equationSolver{
 public:
    static void method1(equation eq, double dt);
}
class simpleMotion : public equation{};
class DragProjectile : public simpleMotion{
void updateVariables(double time){
    equationSolver::method1(this, time); // I am getting error cannot convert 
    // "DragProjectile" to "equation"
}
```

I'd be really glad if you can help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `method1` isn't static. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: You cannot get polymorphism when you pass object parameters by value. Either pass by reference, or pass the address of the object.

Comment: Please paste the **exact literal** error message from the compiler.

Comment: sorry it is static, i just missed it there

Comment: This was already answered the first time you asked this.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass `*this` because your method takes an `equation` by value.  By the way, you might want to change `method1()` to take the `equation` by reference like `equation& eq` or `const equation&` instead, to avoid a copy and to preserve the behavior of any virtual methods you may have (read about "slicing").

Comment: you could add that `this` is const pointer